# Web reference proxy is field specified

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, asmx

I have a WCF service. And in my mobile application I generated a Web References.

I notice that for some fields it also generates a *myFieldSpecified* bool. For example, i have a class Quantity that contains an *int quantity*. on the mobile side it also generates a *bool quantitySpecified*.

What is the purpose of this *specified* field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens if quantity field is not marked as required on the service. Service description than uses this field as nullable and web reference divide the nullable type into non nullable and bool which is saying if field was specified.

Comment: Does it also generate this field when adding a Service References? Or is it only a Web References generation behavior?

Comment: How do you mark the field as required on the service? Which attribute is used for this?

Comment: @Mas: In WCF DataMemberAttribute contains IsRequired property.