# WCF service method

Tags: wcf

I am creating a wcf service in .net. In the service I have added function named XYZ as:

```
public int XYZ(int a){
return a+a;
}
```

When i added the web reference of web service in my web application and accessed the function XYZ, here it requires two parameters one is of int type and second is of bool type.

But originally i had added single parameter in XYZ function in wcf service.

If someone has idea then please let me know that how to handle this. Because my wcf service will be called from flash code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web reference proxy is field specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531117/web-reference-proxy-is-field-specified)

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding a **Web** Reference to your project instead of **Service** Reference then you'll get ["extra" parameters as described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284760/what-are-these-extra-parameters-in-my-asmx-proxy-methods) You should be adding a Service Reference to create a proxy for your service that matches the WCF ServiceContract description of your service. Also, the "extra" parameters only show up for ASMX-based clients. They won't be required for the Flash client to call the WCF Service.

Comment: Thanks Sixo Saex, I got the answer